# Why is the Bind attribute seemingly breaking my model binding of nested objects?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Could someone help me resolve this issue. I'm trying to limit over posting with bind param action but it seems that it doesn't work at all. When I removed the Bind keyword, everything started to work as a charm.

Here is the code sample:

**View Model:**

```
public class ProductCreateViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Product.Id,Product.CategoryId,Product.Description,Product.Title")] ProductCreateViewModel productVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(productVM.Product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories.Include(c => c.Categories).Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == null), "Id", "Name", productVM.Product.CategoryId);
    return View(productVM);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model CatalogWebApp.Models.ProductsViewModels.ProductCreateViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Product";
    ViewData["BigPageTitle"] = "Products";
    ViewData["PageBoxTitle"] = "Add New Product";
}

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Product.CategoryId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="Product.CategoryId" class ="form-control">
                    @foreach(Category item in (ViewBag.CategoryId as SelectList).Items)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                        if (item.Categories != null && item.Categories.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var subCat in item.Categories)
                            {
                                <option value="@subCat.Id">--@subCat.Name</option>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Product.Description" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.Description" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Product.Title" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Product.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.Title" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Could someone pelase indicate if I have a problem or it is only a known asp.net core issue?

Comment: View model should not contain properties which are data models. You view model should contains properties `ID`, `CategoryId`, `Description` etc - i.e. just want you need in the view. And a `[Bind]` attribute is never required when using a view model correctly

Comment: Also you don't need to prefix every single property, just use:
`[Bind("Id", "CategoryId", "Description", "Title", Prefix = nameof(ProductCreateViewModel.Product))]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I followed the MS original article with the DRY(Don't repeat yourself) principle. But found an issue with the file upload since it is not included in the post so I added a VM with the Model and IFromFile collection. For more info please visit the post from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not interested in reading bad articles :)

Comment: The same author who created the tool wrote the article! How this can be bad.
Anyways I learned tons of things from out there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure why you using `Bind` for your case.

Just create sepatate `ViewModel` with only properties you need like `ProductCreateStort`.

Then use this `ViewModel` in your controller signature and inherit your main model from it.

This way you won't mess with `Bind` and limit your params on POST

Answer (score 3):

While I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core myself (and coming to this question 7 months late), I ran into this same issue.  I think the key here is that you have to bind "Product" for it to be considered.  Binding "Product.Id" by itself doesn't appear to be good enough.  So this should work:

```
[Bind("Product,Product.Id,Product.CategoryId,Product.Description,Product.Title")]
```

Of course, Hamid Mosalla's comment is a better option if ALL of your bound properties are on the nested object (which leads to wonder why you need a view model in the first place).  In my case, I have a nested object AND a local property, so using the "Prefix" solution wasn't the right thing to do.

Anyway, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your values as `params string[]`, not as a single `string` separated by commas:

```
[Bind("Product.Id","Product.CategoryId","Product.Description","Product.Title")]
```

See [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4cca6b09f0044660d64469e3278b584a17c356e9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BindAttribute.cs#L29)

Comment: Both of them works fine. Anyways thanks for the , *Prefix = nameof(ProductCreateViewModel.Product)* param!